# Acquire-release memory order between multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model, stdatomic

Code:

```
std::atomic<int> done = 0;
int a = 10;

void f1() {
  a = 20;
  done.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

void f2() {
  if(done.load(std::memory_order_acquired) == 1) {
    assert(a == 20);
  }
}

void f3() {
  if(done.load(std::memory_order_acquired) == 1) {
    assert(a == 20);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(f1);
  std::thread t2(f2);
  std::thread t3(f3);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
}
```

The question is if thread 2 & 3 both see `done == 1`, will 
the assertion `a == 20` hold in both threads ?
I know acquire-release works for a pair of threads. But does 
it work in multiple threads as well?

Comment: I think this is a yes (not confident so not an answer) _"...If an atomic store in thread A is tagged memory_order_release and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged memory_order_acquire, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory...."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering

Comment: Yes because release operation offers transitivity with respect to acquire operation I.e. the release operation will synchronize with second acquire operation. I am sure you can read more about transitivity online.

Comment: Guaranteed? I don't think so since there are no guarantees on the propagation of `a` to other threads. All that `done == 1` is that thread `f1` has changed its local copy of `a` it is unclear how that affects any potentially cached values in the other threads and the timeline for when this value will be visable. Just a thaught cant quote the standard on this.

Comment: @RichardCritten The examples in the link only shows it works for  two threads. I have checked examples in cppreference but didn't see any thing regarding this.

Comment: @MartinYork Which "cache" are you talking about?

Comment: @curiousguy hardware cache. on chip/L1/L2 etc.

Comment: @MartinYork HW caches don't keep stale data around; when a CPU does a store, the location (and whole cache line in fact) is invalidated in others caches.

Comment: @MartinYork: HW caches are coherent, they use MESI to give each core a coherent view of memory.  What you're talking about is usually a mangling of the fact that compilers can load a variable's value into a *register* and assume that the memory location doesn't change.  (e.g. after inlining into a caller that calls multiple times).  So with optimizations like CSE, the code in one thread can *effectively* be using an old value for a global because the asm doesn't actually reload it.  (There's also the store buffer; a seq_cst store has to flush the SB to delay later loads until it's visible)

Comment: @MartinYork: But anyway, the acquire load is a one-way memory barrier that establishes a happens-before relationship with a thread that did a release store that we see.  This forces the compiler to reload non-atomic vars because it's possible they now have different values.  (And on weakly-ordered ISAs, to use any necessary barrier to give LoadLoad and LoadStore ordering).  Then it's just up to the HW, which as discussed maintains a coherent view of memory between all caches.

Comment: @PeterCordes There is also the potential for obvious optimizations like `if(x==2) { y=1; z=x; }` which can usually be compiled w/o a reload of `x` (set `z` to 2 no matter what) which isn't valid of `x` is shared and allowed to be changed concurrently.

Comment: @curiousguy: That's exactly the kind of thing I meant by "optimizations like CSE".  Although actually that optimization *is* still valid if we assume `atomic<int> x,y,z;` and that all the accesses are with acq_rel ordering.  Then one of the possible orderings in the abstract machine is for the 2nd read of `x` to read the same value as the 1st, so the compiler can pick that at compile time.  A z=1 release-store doesn't have to wait to become globally visible before the 2nd `x` load.  (Optimization of atomics is a thorny problem, though; current compilers choose not to at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The release-acquire relationship holds separately for **all** pairs of threads (that access the same atomic location!) and guarantees that **all** writes (that appear in program order) before the release are visible to **all** reads (that appear in program order) after whichever corresponding acquire.

Comment: I see. This makes sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A release is like publishing a newspaper (one with no defined periodicity), and acquire is like buying the later edition right now, then discovering what it says (not caring which edition it is, or which day it is). (You rarely need to do versioning on these shared atomics, although it can sometimes be needed.)

Any number of people can buy the newspaper. What matters is that what's printed was true when it was printed, and is still true if they are invariant truths, like the creation of a monument (invariable by hypothesis).

So a release operation publishes what is true at the time of publication, and proper design guarantees that these facts cannot have changed when you can "buy" (acquire) the publication. Any number of threads can see these facts.